# Facebook Graph API only returns my own reactions to my posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have set up a test page on Facebook to use with my Facebook app.

On the permissions part, I have allowed all permissions including `read insights`

[image]

With this, I am able to fetch things such as the feed, visitor posts, comments, etc.

The problem starts when I try to fetch reactions to my page feed.
I basically call the post id and reactions as below:

```
<post-id>/reactions
```

This, however, only returns the reactions that I made as the page admin.
If any other Facebook user reacts on my page feed, their reactions do not show up

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: What kind of token did you use?

Comment: I am using the page token

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v10.0/object/reactions says, _“A User or Page can only query their own reactions. Other Users' or Pages' reactions are unavailable due to privacy concerns.”_ That does not appear to be entirely true though, for page feeds, I am able to see reactions made by other pages at least, when I am using a page token.

Comment: This is what has been confusing me. The documentation says one cannot access reactions made by others but everywhere I look online, people are able to query the reactions. Furthermore, I am able to query comments and visitor posts on the page. It is very weird